# Recursive render with array of objects inside React Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context

I have a React Native code, which consists of a Markdown editor that parses the text and extracts information about Headers. I plan to build a menu with the headers and when clicked jump to the header inside the editor. Something like a Table of Contents.

```
const Editor = ({ initValue, style, onChange = () => {} }: EditorProps) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>(initValue);
  const { setHeaderNodes } = useHeaderNavigation();

  const changeHandler = (text: string) => {
    setValue(text);
    onChange(text);
  };
  const ast = parse(value);

  const headers: HeaderNavigationNode[] = useMemo(() => {
    return ast.filter(isHeaderNode).map(node => {
      const { content, loc: { start: { line } } } = node;
      return { content, line };
    });
  }, [ast]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setHeaderNodes(headers);
  }, [headers]);

  console.log(JSON.stringify(headers, null, 4));
  ...
};

// Context.ts
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react';

export interface HeaderNavigationNode {
  content: string;
  line: number;
}

export interface Context {
  headerNodes: HeaderNavigationNode[];
  setHeaderNodes: (nodes: HeaderNavigationNode[]) => void;
}

export const NavigationContext = createContext<Context>(null)

export const useHeaderNavigation = () => useContext(NavigationContext);

// App.tsx
export default function App() {
  const [headerNodes, setHeaderNodes] = useState<HeaderNavigationNode[]>([]);
  return (
    <NavigationContext.Provider value={{ headerNodes, setHeaderNodes }}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Main" drawerContent={CustomDrawer}>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </NavigationContext.Provider>
  );
}

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Editor
        initValue={`# HEADER 1

\`\`\`
function hello(name) {
   return \`hello $\{name}\`;
}
\`\`\``} />
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

The problem is that it this creates infinite loop of rerender. I've tried to add useMemo for the `headers` but this didn't fix the issue. I think that I add React.memo for the editor. But this sounds like a hack the same as useMemo in my code.

What should I do to make the array inside Context doesn't rerender everything in a loop?

I know that `ast` is new array/object each time the components re-render so I need some kind of deep checking if the array of HeaderNodes is the same as before when calling `setHeaderNodes` but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: The `useMemo` for `headers` is not enough, it depends on `ast` which is recreated on every render. You'll also need a `useMemo` for `ast` being parsed from  `value`, as *that* is the state which doesn't change while re-rendering in a different `NavigationContext`.

Comment: Really you should consider hoisting the `value`/`ast` state into the `App` to avoid the need for that effect

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure how to do that. I've modified my code a bit. I wanted to simplify the example and put `<Editor>` inside `<App>` but in fact this is a React Native project that uses React Navigation.

Comment: Not sure how that is related - are you passing the `headerNodes` to the react navigation somewhere, or is the doubt related to the `<Editor>` being shown only on some screens not always?

Comment: @Bergi The editor will be always on the screen. But it's related in a way that I don't create instance of the Editor with JSX only pass the component as prop. So I can't use onChange to pass the value from Editor to App. And I need this in App because I plan to use header info in the menu (Drawer).

Comment: Ok, I see. To solve that, you can pass the `value` and `setValue` using the `NavigationContext` instead of via props from the app to the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue by serializing the headers array to a string and using that as a dependency:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setHeaderNodes(headers);
  }, [JSON.stringify(headers)]);
```

The component is rendered twice when `headers` change but I don't think you can do anything with this issue.